# ¿Como puedo limitar el tamaño del año en entrada tipo date?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un campo de tipo date que funciona correctamente a excepción de una cosa, el problema esta en que al momento de ingresar el año me permite hacer algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo lo que realmente quiero es que solo se permita 4 digitos maximo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa en el *input* los atributos `min` y `max` para indicar desde que fecha iniciaría y en que fecha terminaría, eso ayudará a que no se puedan ingresar mas de 4 números en el año; así:

Recuerda que el formato es `YYYY-MM-DD` entonces colócalo en ese orden

```html
    <input type="date" min="2019-04-01" max="2999-09-21">
```